# "Rendered" View style for a Taxonomy Term?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

When creating a View for content Nodes, the "Format > Show" options includes "teasers" and "full posts" in addition to "fields". But for Taxonomy Terms, the only option appears to be "fields". I have Taxonomy Terms that have additional fields attached, and have the Display Preferences set to show/hide various fields for a teaser/full display of that term. Since different Taxonomy Terms have different fields, I want to use the Term's configuration rather than hard-code it into the View.

Is there a way to add a rendered View of a Term itself? Or do I need to create a separate View for each Term I want to summarize and define the "teaser" display again in the View?

Comment: I do not see a way to add multiple bundles for a taxonomy term; however, when I make a view of taxonomy term children, one of the options that I see in addition to "fields" is "rendered entity".  This selection renders all of the fields that are selected as visible in the taxonomy term's "manage display" settings page. Although there is only one view type, it does at least behave as you wish vis-a-vis respecting the term's (single) configuration. In my site, I further optimize the display in a render hook ; this could emulate "teaser" modes. Don't know if you can do it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

At "Format > Show" there is an option "Rendered entity".

Apply it and then you can choose term's "View mode" in the select dropdown.

Also you can install [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/DS) and notice new option "Display suite" at "Format > Show".